# fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'pack.deltacachesize': invalid unit

Tags: github

when I use git push,I get an error like this "Pushing to https://windming@bitbucket.org/windming/kjzjchange-v2.git
fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'pack.deltacachesize': invalid unit
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

the detail info is "git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master 
Pushing to https://windming@bitbucket.org/windming/kjzjchange-v2.git
fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'pack.deltacachesize': invalid unit
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

git push

figure out the problem

Answer (score 5):

git config --global pack.deltacachesize 128m